# sans-serif-thin is italic by default?

Tags: android

I am trying to use the roboto-thin font in one of my layouts but when I set the font family to "sans-serif-thin" the font is italic by default and I am unable to force it to be normal.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstLabel"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:text="for this week"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />
```

Can anyone tell me the right way to use the roboto-thin normal style font in a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on my 4.2.2 and 2.2 devices, all show normal font, no italic. Maybe you have dynamically set a different text style somewhere in your code.

Comment: Well, you are right. The thing is, on the Graphical Layout designer (or previewer if you will) it does show italic style.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think anyone can guarantee the correctness of the previewer. The safest way is always to test it on emulator, or even better, a real device whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the folder fonts on asset folder and drop your font XX.ttf in there. 
Then, use that :

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "XX.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: Yep, that would be the case if I wanted to use the font on devices below 4.1 if i'm not mistaken. Roboto font is included by default from 4.1 on.

Thanks for the help tho! :)